# Binding empty list or null value to table valued parameter on a stored procedure (.NET)

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I have created a stored procedure that takes a table valued parameter that is a table with a single column of type `int`.  The idea is to simply pass a list of ids into the store procedure and allow the stored procedure to work with the data.  However, in the case where there is no data to pass in, I am encountering problems (things work correctly when I have data).  I am converting a `List<int>` to an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`, and binding that to the table valued parameter for the stored procedure.  I have tried to bind an empty `List<SqlDataRecord>`, which resulted in the error:

> System.ArgumentException: There are no records in the SqlDataRecord enumeration. To send a table-valued parameter with no rows, use a null reference for the value instead.

I then tried to bind a null value (which I thought was what the above message was getting at), but that only resulted in a different error message

> System.NotSupportedException: DBNull value for parameter '@MainItemIdList' is not supported. Table-valued parameters cannot be DBNull.

It does not appear that you can declare the table valued parameter as nullable in the stored procedure declaration.  What is the correct method for binding an empty list to at table valued parameter?

Answer (score 98):

The trick is: **don’t pass in the parameter at all**. The default value for a table-valued parameter is an empty table.

It is a shame that the exception message is so unhelpful.

Comment: It never hurts to add a new answer or improve one. The information is still relevant and someone else will find it useful (that's the whole point of this site!). +1

Comment: Any idea how to do this if using plain old table adapters? TableAdapter templates a CLR proxy function with the same signature as the SP, and it expects a not-null value. Passing null or DbNull.Value throws an error.

Comment: Up 1. This is exactly what I needed to do - tested and it works great.

Comment: +1 big thanks - confirmed this works for the `SqlDataRecord` / `SqlMetaData` approach to TVPs as well.

Comment: So, how would I change the code to not pass a parameter? In my case I have 5 TVPs parameters and each may be empty. I'm using code like this one 
BenefitsItemsLinkCollection itemsCollection = new BenefitsItemsLinkCollection();
            itemsCollection.AddRange(items);
            itemsPar.Value = itemsCollection;
            itemsPar.TypeName = "siriusType_BenefitLinkedItems";
What should I change here for empty array of items?

Comment: Agreed on the exception message. There is little chance I would have even tried this fix without your help!

Answer (score 7):

I was a bit confused by what the 'not passing the parameter' statement means. What ends up working for Entity Framework ExecuteSqlCommandAsync() is this:

```
  new SqlParameter("yourParameterName", SqlDbType.Structured)
  {
      Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
      TypeName = "yourUdtType",
      Value = null
  };
```

This will pass the parameter as 'default'.

Comment: Not sure why it works for you, but this does not work at all for me. I get the exact error messages in the original question when using this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Not passing a value **does** work but not in the case where I had multiple table value parameters to pass into the procedure. How I solved it was to specify a value of `DEFAULT` in my query string.  For example,

```
string sqlQuery = "[dbo].[GetOrderData] @QueueId";

if (OrderIdList.Any())
{
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + ", @OrderIdList";
}
else
{
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + ", DEFAULT";
}

if (RegionIdList.Any())
{
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + ", @RegionIdList";
}
else
{
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery + ", DEFAULT";
}
```

Kudos to http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#Invoking where I found the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I get the error when passing an empty `IEnumerable<int>` but it works fine when I pass an empty `List<int>` instead.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get the same error whether passing an IEnumerable or List.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion comes because when the error message states, "use a null reference for the value instead", it means C# `null`, not `DBNull.Value`.  Setting a parameter to C# `null` passes the default value for the parameter, which in the case of a table-valued parameter is an empty table.  Setting the value to `DBNull.Value` passes as SQL `NULL` value, which is not valid for a table-valued parameter.