# Passing empty list to user defined table type parameter on a scalar function

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, user-defined-types

So I have this user-defined table type parameter, which is used in my scalar function and might be empty.
I've read this topic about passing empty list to table-valued parameter on a stored procedure:
[Binding empty list or null value to table valued parameter on a stored procedure (.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630632/binding-empty-list-or-null-value-to-table-valued-parameter-on-a-stored-procedure) 
And basically, as one of the repliers said:

> "The trick is: **don’t pass in the parameter at all**. The default
>   value for a table-valued parameter is an empty table"

However, when I try this on scalar function, I get an error:

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or
>   function

So how do I pass empty value to table-valued parameter on a scalar function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments to functions aren't optional, so you need to pass a compatible TVP to the function. I'm not sure I understand the point of a scalar-valued function that takes a TVP type but doesn't need to - what does this function do and how can it do it without the TVP? Are you sure this isn't meant to be a TVF?

Anyway here is how you can pass an empty TVP to a scalar function:

```
DECLARE @x dbo.TVP_type_name;
SELECT dbo.function_name(@x);
```

Comment: This scalar-valued function is supposed to return a total search result count. It basically has same parameters as my stored procedure, except my SP returns query result and has two additional parameters for pagination - "page number" and "rows per page". Thanks for help, I see now that I need to declare these TVPs explicitly.